# Understanding the idea of "also" (I am ready if you are)

Tags: adverb, word-usage

Like my previous question about "once," another English concept that can be tricky and have multiple means is "also". So, for example, something can also happen (subsequent action), or you can bring one thing and also another (addition), or concerning state of being, if I am sick, then my sibling can *also* be sick (sameness or likeness of condition). So, we have variant ideas for the same word in English, that may or may not be rendered by different words in Latin.

Here, I am mostly wondering about the "also" in the sense of likeness of condition. For example, let's imagine we want to say "I am ready if you are". One way to do this might be along the lines of the following:

**sum paratus etiam fore te eris**

In this expression, I did not write a Latin "if" but instead tried to imply it by the future subjunctive which seems to be a standard pattern for dealing with hypotheticals. Literally we have "I am ready (assuming) you might be going to be also". So, where in English we would use the present tense, in Latin, since it is a hypothetical it is future subjunctive. Now let's look at a similar sentence from Plautus:

**si te emam, mihi quoque Lucridem confido fore te.**

Literally, it means "If I might buy you, I am confident you are about to be also a Lucrativeness for me." or as we would say in English "If I buy you, I expect you to be profitable for me." Notice how he uses the future subjunctive (*te emam*) for the hypothetical, where in English we use the present tense.

So, my question revolves around the ALSO in the sentences. In my sentence I have tried ***etiam***, but in Plautus he writes ***quoque***. So, the question is how do we decide how to choose the word for "also" in a situation like "I am ready if you are" (sameness of condition). Note that in the sentence of Plautus, it is not sameness of condition, but a more of a conjunction or addition, so it is not the same usage as in my sentence. In fact, I am not even sure if *quoque* is supposed to be a conjunction or an adverb in that sentence.

Anyway, we can see there are different possible words for the idea 'also' and so I am wondering about how we sort them out in the case I have outlined, "I am ready if you are (too/also)". Note that in many such situations, Romans use the plain old ***et***, so maybe that is right?

Comment: I'm pretty confused by this question. "Also" plays the same function in all three examples: you're just talking about a difference in the predicate ("happening" vs. "being sick"). As a side note, *sim paratus etiam fore te eris* makes no syntactical sense.

Comment: @brianpck There is a difference between one thing happening and also another (different) thing happening (we captured the fort and also the town), and between two things being in the same condition (I am young and my friend is also young).

Comment: @brianpck Even you disagree with this basic premise, you cannot disagree that there are multiple words in Latin for also (etiam, quoque and et, among others), so the question can be answered simply by explaining how these words should be situationally used or why one should be preferred in a given context like the English sentence I gave  (I am ready if you are (also) ready). So, you don't need to have some kind of dogmatic agreement with everything in the question in order to answer it.

Comment: @Tyler Durden: In, "sim paratus etiam fore te eris", why deploy a subjunctive ("sim")?

Comment: @tony That seems to be a practice when talking about hypothetical situations. For example, this line from Apuleis: "cum sim paratus vel uno saviolo interim recreatus super istum ignem porrectus assari" ("I am prepared, if you will revive me now with one little kiss, to be stretched out over your fire and barbecued.") Notice how Lucius says "sim paratus", not "sum paratus". I think this is because the whole sentence is hypothetical. In English we only make the conditional part qualified, but the Romans seemed to want to make the entirety subjunctive if it involved a hypothetical scenario.

Comment: @TylerDurden in your Apuleius quote, isn’t the subjunctive to be attributed to the cum?

Comment: @Kingshorsey Ah ha, I was not aware of that. I guess so. I edited my sentence to use the plain present. I did not know about that use of cum.

Comment: Where is "also" in the sentence "I am ready if you are"?

Comment: @cmw The phrase can be thought of as meaning "I am ready if you are also"; it can also be phrased "I am ready if you are too". I suppose "too" is very close to meaning "also" in this usage.